# First letter cuts off with Italic font in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have added italic font to `UITextField` with `UITextAlignmentLeft`. When user type character for e.g. "j", this character cuts off in left side. I have tried to add padding, custom `textrectBounds` & `editingtextRectBounds` but none of them works.

Comment: Have you tried to update the insets?

Comment: I have tried to override the method of UITextFeld
(CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 2, 0);
} but this is not worked for me. First letter still cuts off

Comment: What happens when you increase the inset of the dx in the CGRectInset,

For example CGRectInset(bounds, 10, 0);

Comment: Its just shift the editing rect to 10px & the character still cuts off from left.

Comment: The same here, change the insets move the text but still cutting on italic. I did tried with "textRectForBounds" + "editingRectForBounds", and with "drawTextInRect"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a super-simple subclass of UILabel:

```
class PaddingLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 2, bottom: 0, right: 2)
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }
}
```

Then, make your UILabel class to **PaddingLabel** and adjust the insets values depending on your needs.